# Error when upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 on AWS EC2 web server

Tags: server, upgrade, python, amazon-ec2

I had done the following:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo reboot


Here is a console copy of the issue after I do the sudo do-release-upgrade

sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,248 kB]
Fetched 1,248 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1981, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1153, in askDistUpgrade
    changes = self.calcDistUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1120, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 856, in installTasks
    pkg.mark_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1356, in mark_install
    fixer.resolve(True)
SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 497, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 450, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2072, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1981, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1153, in askDistUpgrade
    changes = self.calcDistUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1120, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l_t30ks4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 856, in installTasks
    pkg.mark_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1356, in mark_install
    fixer.resolve(True)
SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Sun Apr 18 09:27:05 2021) ===
```

How d I recover and what caused this issue.

Jack

Comment: You may need to reinstall python with the version of the python that comes with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please do not upgrade instances and create a NEW instance at the AWS console and then attach your data partition to this new system disk. IF your upgrade fails and the boot errors out you lost your instance. AWS provides containers for all LTS versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I have not used AWS, but on my PC I have used sudo apt-get -f install to fix dependences. And there is an apt command to un-hold packages too, which I think you need to do 1st

Comment: Rinzwind - I did an in place upgrade.

Comment: FedonKadifeli  -  I restarted the upgrade to 18.04  and all went wel.  Now I see that the version of python is  python3 -V
Python 3.6.9

Comment: @JackStein sure but do be warned: if the system kills your boot the instance IS gone. Don't take the risk if you have a production system. If you are toying around go for it. But the idea using instances is to use a system disk and a personal disk. system disk you set up at the AWS console and then you attach your personal disk. Far less risky.

Comment: Rinzwind - thanks for the tip.  As a SOP I ran the AWS on demand backup of the instance before doing the in place upgrade.  I kept the backup around for a 2 week retention period.  I could make it longer.  I had a previous  experience where I had to restore the backup and AWS created a new instance with the backed up instance to allow me to recover.